# limitation of numbers and types of custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im using a custom directive available online, and it works really fine, but there is only one change that i need to make, for example in the directive im able to limite decimal numbers or to int, and i can use commas or dots, the only problem is when i load data from the server, in the database it comes with a dot, and i liked to when is loaded first time from the db it comes with a comma instead of a dot. I tried replacing above $parsers function using "replace('.',','), but than is always changing it, not letting the user instead putting or a dot or a comma.
So basically i need when is first loaded from db, it comes with a comma.

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('onlyNumber', function() {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                var decRegexp, intRegexp;

                intRegexp = /^(\d*)/;
                decRegexp = "^(\\d*(\\.|,)?(\\d{1,DECIMALS})?)";
                decRegexp = new RegExp(decRegexp.replace('DECIMALS', ''+attrs.decimalUpto));

  // I tried this above but isnt updating the input/view
 var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            var value = getter($scope);
            if(value){
            ngModel.$setViewValue(value.replace('.', ','));
            ngModel.$render();
            }


                ngModel.$parsers.push(function (val) {


                    var isDec, parsed, ref, regexp;
                    isDec = attrs.numType === 'decimal';

                    regexp = isDec ? decRegexp : intRegexp;
                    parsed = val != null ? (ref = val.match(regexp)) != null ? ref[0] : void 0 : void 0;
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(parsed);
                    ngModel.$render();

                    if(isDec){

                        var result = parseFloat(parsed.replace(',', '.'));
                        if (attrs.minLimit > result) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartFloatMin', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }else
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartFloatMin', true);



                        if (attrs.maxLimit < result) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartFloatMax', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }else
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartFloatMax', true);
                    }else{
                        var result = parseInt(parsed);

                        if (attrs.minLimit > result) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartIntegerMin', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }else
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartIntegerMin', true);



                        if (attrs.maxLimit < result) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartIntegerMax', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }else
                            ngModel.$setValidity('smartIntegerMax', true);
                    }


                    return result;
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Try $formaters.push() instead of $parsers.push(). $parsers.push for viewVale not modelValue!

Comment: Can you show your view code?

Answer (score 0):

In the your directive use it like this

```
  ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
    return modelValue.replace(/\./g,',') ;
  })
```

[here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cxqxPsT6nPcXIWdLEJTo?p=preview)